# Why my Laravel blade view returns blank page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

this is my route

```php
Route::get('/product/single/{slug}', 'Front\ShopController@shopSingle')
->name('front.shop_single.ru');
```

and my view where I use that route to load single product

```
<div class="col-md-4">                
    <div class="product">
    <figure class="product-image">
        <a href="{{ route('front.shop_single.ru', $product->slug ) }}"><img src="/{{ $img[0]  }}" alt="bitcoin, bitcoindoc, bitcoin exchange, exchange, libradoc, libradoc exchange"></a>
        <a href="{{ route('front.shop_single.ru', $product->slug) }}" class="btn btn-style-4"><i class="licon-cart"></i>Подробно</a>
    </figure>
    <div class="product-description">
        <a href="{{ route('front.shop_single.ru', $product->slug ) }}" class="product-cat">{{ $product->title  }}</a>
        <h5 class="product-name"><a href="{{ route('front.shop_single.ru', $product->slug ) }}">{{ $product->price  }}</a></h5>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

finally controller to redirect my desired page

```php
public function shopSingle($slug){
    $product = Shop::whereSlug($slug)->whereLang(App::getLocale())->first();
    $data['product'] = $product;
    return view('front.'.'App::getLocale()'.'.shop_single', $data);        
}
```

unfortunately, whenever I try to go to single product it returns blank page but in the view page resource(I use Chrome) everything is okay. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: which laravel/blade version are you using?

Comment: Can you show the json format of $product?

Comment: @user10971804 even when i send without data still the same result, I guess it is smth blade related error

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the last line from your controller to

```
return view('front.'.App::getLocale().'.shop_single', ['product' => $product]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data as well to your view

```
public function shopSingle($slug){

    $product = Shop::whereSlug($slug)->whereLang(App::getLocale())->first();

    // it could work like this
    $data['product'] = $product;
    return view('front.'.App::getLocale().'.shop_single', $data);

    // or
    return view('front.'.App::getLocale().'.shop_single', compact($product));

    // or
    return view('front.'.App::getLocale().'.shop_single')->withProduct($product);
}
```

Comment: No errors shown, as I understand the problem is with the view, because function returns other other pages successfully and route is also correct it redirects to right function but when i include extend layout and include header, footer problem ocurs  '@extends('front.layouts.master')
                          @section('content')                                                           
                              ##content##                              
                           @endsection'     this format works in other views but here it creates trouble